# How to find week of the month

Tags: java

I like to know which week of the month a particular day falls. For example 20-Sep-2012 falls on 4th week of September but the below code displays it as 3 which is not correct. The system is dividing the days by 7 and returning the output and which is not I require. I have searched in Joda API's but not able to find the solution. Please let me know is there any way to figure out the week of a month, a day falls

```
    Calendar ca1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    ca1.set(2012,9,20);

    int wk=ca1.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("Week of Month :"+wk);
```

Comment: "...  which is not I require" - well, then what exactly *do* you require? Get those rules clear, and then you can write them down in Java code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to two reasons:

The first one is this (from the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)):

> *The first week of a month or year is defined as the earliest seven day period beginning on getFirstDayOfWeek() and containing at least
>   getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days*

The default value for this varies (mine was 4), but you can set this to your preferred value with

[Calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek%28int%29)

The second reason is the one @Timmy brought up in his answer. You need to perform both changes for your code to work. Complete working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar ca1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    ca1.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 20);
    ca1.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(1);
    int wk = ca1.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("Week of Month :" + wk);
}
```

This prints

```
Week of Month :4
```

Comment: By invoking the ca1.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(2); still it is returning as 3. I was trying to figure out any standard API is there but I think there is no API existing in Calendar or Joda date. I came to the conclusion I have to write the code to determine the week of a month of a particular day

Answer (score 4):

Month is zero-based. So ca1.set(2012,9,20) is actually setting the calendar to October.

Comment: By setting the month, it is still displaying week as 3 and not 4 ca1.set(2012,Calendar.SEPTEMBER,20);

Comment: Weird. On my machine, it returns 4.

Answer (score 1):

To get sure the right month is set try using the month-constants provided by the Calendar-Class.

Answer (score 0):

For those working with Joda time, this is what I am using:

```
/**
 * For a week starting from Sunday, get the week of the month assuming a
 * valid week is any week containing at least one day.
 * 
 * 0=Last,1=First,2=Second...5=Fifth
 */
private int getWeekOfMonth( MutableDateTime calendar )
{
    long time = calendar.getMillis();
    int dayOfMonth = calendar.getDayOfMonth();
    int firstWeekday;
    int lastDateOfMonth;
    int week;
    int weeksInMonth;

    calendar.setDayOfMonth( 1 );
    firstWeekday = calendar.getDayOfWeek();
    if (firstWeekday == 7)
    {
        firstWeekday = 0;
    }
    calendar.setHourOfDay( 0 );
    calendar.addMonths( 1 );
    calendar.addDays( -1 );
    lastDateOfMonth = calendar.getDayOfMonth();
    weeksInMonth = (int)Math.ceil( 1.0*(lastDateOfMonth + firstWeekday)/7 );
    week = (byte)(1 + (dayOfMonth + firstWeekday - 1)/7);
    week = (week == weeksInMonth)?0:week;
    calendar.setMillis( time );

    return week;
}
```

Comment: what and how to pass in this method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to this question, but I feel the full answer is missing, which is, that how weeks are interpreted can differ quite a lot depending on the `Locale`.

The question seems to need the settings for the US (or a similar `Locale`), which uses 1 as minimal days in first week, and Sunday as the first day of the week.

The question, and all the answers take a default `Calendar` instance which comes with 4 as minimal days in first week, and Monday as first day of the week.

A simple demo program shows this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        System.out.println("--- ISO ---");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("First day of week        : " + calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
        System.out.println("Minimal days in 1st week : " + calendar.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());
        calendar.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 20);
        int wk = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println("Week of Month : " + wk);
    }
    {
        System.out.println("--- USA ---");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
        System.out.println("First day of week        : " + calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
        System.out.println("Minimal days in 1st week : " + calendar.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());
        calendar.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 20);
        int wk = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println("Week of Month : " + wk);
    }
}
```

And that yields this output :

```
--- ISO ---
First day of week        : 2
Minimal days in 1st week : 4
Week of Month : 3
--- USA ---
First day of week        : 1
Minimal days in 1st week : 1
Week of Month : 4
```

**CONCLUSION** :

There's no need to manually set the minimal days in first week, or the first day of week. Just make sure you're using the right `Locale`.

**Extra**

Joda time only had support for ISO weeks.
Since Java 8 and the new time API you can go about it like this :

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2012, 9, 20);
TemporalField usWeekOfMonth = WeekFields.of(Locale.US).weekOfMonth();
TemporalField isoWeekOfMonth = WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth();
System.out.println("USA week of month " + usWeekOfMonth.getFrom(localDate));
System.out.println("ISO week of month " + usWeekOfMonth.getFrom(localDate));
```

Output :

```
USA week of month 4
ISO week of month 4
```

And there's even support in the formatter :

```
DateTimeFormatter usDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("W/MM")
        .withLocale(Locale.US);
System.out.println("USA formatter : " + usDateTimeFormatter.format(localDate));
DateTimeFormatter isoDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("W/MM");
System.out.println("ISO formatter : " + isoDateTimeFormatter.format(localDate));
```

Output :

```
USA formatter : 4/09
ISO formatter : 3/09
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();      
        cal.set(2016, Calendar.AUGUST, 01);
        printDayOFWeek(cal, Calendar.MONDAY, 5);//prints monday on 5th week
    }
}

private static void printDayOFWeek(Calendar cal, int day, int whatweek) {
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);//day = Mon, tue, wed,..etc
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, -1); //-1 return last week 

    Date last = cal.getTime();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, whatweek);

    Date one = cal.getTime();
    if(one.before(last) || one.compareTo(last) ==0)
    {
      System.out.println(whatweek +"WEEK" + cal.getTime());
    }
}
```